# Scientist4J - Unable to produce a mismatch even when the candidate path is set to null intentionally

Tags: java, github, path

I am trying to experiment with Scientist4j.  Mostly as a way to check if there is a mismatch in response between the new and old code paths.
But i cannot seem to trigger a Mismatch. Even if i intentionally sent the response on the candidate path to `null`.
Not sure what i am missing.

Here is a sample of my code calling the experiment

```
//Calling the candidate path with startTime, startTime(instead of endtime) to see what mismatch would look like

callWithExperiment(() -> getAnalyticsInfos(startTime, startTime), "Running candidate `getAnalyticsInfoByTime`");

private <T> List<T> callWithExperiment(Callable<List<T>> callable, String logMessage) {
        try {
            final DropwizardMetricsProvider dropwizardMetricsProvider = new DropwizardMetricsProvider();
            Experiment<List<T>> experiment = new Experiment<>("analytics-experiment", dropwizardMetricsProvider);
            experiment.run(
                    () -> callable.call(),
                    () -> {
                        log.info(logMessage);
                        Random random = new Random();
                        Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(5) * 100);
                        return callable.call();
             });

              ConsoleReporter reporter = ConsoleReporter.forRegistry((MetricRegistry) experiment.getMetricsProvider().getRegistry())
                .convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
             reporter.start(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
             reporter.report();
             reporter.stop();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Below is where i am trying to introduce a mismatch by setting the analytics result to `null`.

```
 private List<AnalyticsInfo> getAnalyticsInfos(long startTime, long endTime) {
        return withClient(client -> {
            GetAnalyticsInfoRequest req = new GetAnalyticsInfoRequest().setStartTime(startTime).setEndTime(endTime);
            GetAnalyticsInfoResponse resp = client.geAnalyticsInfo(req);
            List<AnalyticsInfo> results = resp.getInfo();
//Intentionally setting bad response when startTime == endTime
            if(startTime == endTime){
                log.info("Updating results to null");
                results = null;
            }
            if(results != null){
                return results.parallelStream()
                        .map(Transformer::toAnalyticsInfo)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
```

Here are the my results from the experiment

```
3/31/23 9:39:50 PM =============================================================
-- Counters --------------------------------------------------------------------
scientist.analytics-experiment.candidate.exception
count = 0
scientist.analytics-experiment.mismatch
count = 0
scientist.analytics-experiment.total
count = 1
-- Timers ----------------------------------------------------------------------
scientist.analytics-experiment.candidate
count = 1
sum = 24135238
mean rate = 9.77 calls/second
1-minute rate = 0.00 calls/second
5-minute rate = 0.00 calls/second
15-minute rate = 0.00 calls/second
min = 24.14 milliseconds
max = 24.14 milliseconds
mean = 24.14 milliseconds
stddev = 0.00 milliseconds
median = 24.14 milliseconds
75% <= 24.14 milliseconds
95% <= 24.14 milliseconds
98% <= 24.14 milliseconds
99% <= 24.14 milliseconds
99.9% <= 24.14 milliseconds
scientist.analytics-experiment.control
count = 1
sum = 76235890
mean rate = 9.73 calls/second
1-minute rate = 0.00 calls/second
5-minute rate = 0.00 calls/second
15-minute rate = 0.00 calls/second
min = 76.24 milliseconds
max = 76.24 milliseconds
mean = 76.24 milliseconds
stddev = 0.00 milliseconds
median = 76.24 milliseconds
75% <= 76.24 milliseconds
95% <= 76.24 milliseconds
98% <= 76.24 milliseconds
99% <= 76.24 milliseconds
99.9% <= 76.24 milliseconds
```

If someone can let me know if i am missing something that would be great

Comment: This was my bad.
I thought i was calling the candidate/control with two different lambdas, but i had reverted that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my bad. I thought i was calling the candidate/control with two different lambdas, but i haI do see the mismatch now

```
scientist.test-experiment.candidate.exception count = 0 
scientist.test-experiment.mismatch count = 1
```

Adding a new `Callable` for candidate as the second argument and passing in below, fixed my issue

```
callWithExperiment(() -> getAnalyticsInfos(startTime, endTime), 
() -> getAnalyticsInfos(startTime, startTime),
"Running candidate `getAnalyticsInfoByTime`");
```